# PrimeFaces 4.0.5: random IllegalStateException with p:poll component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, mojarra

I have a chat application where I use a p:poll component to periodically check for new messages.

After I migrated from 3.5.20 to 4.0.5 I started to get random java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response(stacktrace below).

Other pages work fine, only difference between them is the poll component. Tested with Mojarra 2.1.26 and 2.2.4.

Time to the exception happen vary a lot. It can be 5 minutes, it can be 2 hours. No special interaction needed, if I just leave the page opened the exception will happen, another reason why I think the problem might be the poll component.

I'm aware that the poll component passed through some refactor in PrimeFaces 4: https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5330

Could the modifications in the component be related? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Phillip

```
Dec 17, 2013 8:22:49 AM org.primefaces.expression.SearchExpressionFacade resolveComponentForClient
WARNING: Can not update component without a attached renderer. Component class: "class org.primefaces.component.tabview.Tab"
Dec 17, 2013 8:23:35 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/page/atendimento/atendimentos.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:638)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:214)
   at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:834)
   at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:415)
   at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
   at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
   at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
   at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at br.com.spdata.tecnico.filter.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:34)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
   at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
   at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
   at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
   at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
   at com.googlecode.psiprobe.Tomcat70AgentValve.invoke(Tomcat70AgentValve.java:38)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but problem was caused by atmosphere-runtime. Changing to atmosphere-runtime-native solved the problem.

My mistake was migrating from PF 3.5 to 4 and enabling push at the same time, so it was much harder to troubleshoot the root of the problem.